# How to represent this app trick?

Tags: gui-design, android, mobile-application

I  have designed an Android app for love calculator, but I have given two radio buttons on the  upper left and right corner :

[image]

These radio buttons don't have any labels because they are used to preform a trick in calculation.If left radio-button is checked the love % would be more and less if the right radio button is checked.It behaves normal if none of them is checked.

But this looks really awful.I need a better stuff to preform this trick.
There should be something in my GUI that will tell me how the user wants to manipulate the result.

Any help related to new logic or representation of similar logic will be appreciated.
But one should note that this thing should not be notable enough as its a trick.

**UPDATE :**

Well these radio buttons are kind of preferences of user.
For example, if user clicked left -->do this
                clicked right -->do this

but this "click" thingy should not be noticeable.
Like for example if i use a swipe kind of a thing, swipe left--> do this...
so, it may not be noticeable, but will give me user's preference.

**UPDATE 2 :**

Sorry for trouble, i'll try to explain again.
So, I am making an app which gives your love percentage (a love percentage calculator).
But, here I am giving the user an option to cheat. For example : joe wants to show their love percentage to luci , but joe wants there love % should cross 95 every time.So what joe did was, he secretly pressed a radio button on the left hand side of the app, which is used to increase your love %.(also he can decrease the love % by pressing the radio button on the other side). After doing the same thing, luci came to know that the radio button was a cheat(she noticed). So here is the problem. What should one use instead of radio buttons(a good alternative ) so that it is not noticeable as much as the radio buttons thingy. For example one can use swipe left to decrease your %, or swipe right to increase.
So I was looking for the alternative which is least noticeable, and easy to use.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you try to explain the problem one more time. It's hard to understand. What role has the radio buttons? It is about preference or something?

Comment: @TonyBolero exactly ! its a kind of preference.I'll update.

Comment: @downvoter Please mention the reasons for your down-vote.Thanks.

Comment: This is quite a confusing question. I think the issue is that you've not really explained the *problem* that your radiobutton implementation is addressing, you've just discussed why this solution isn't really working. But without really knowing what the problem is that this is trying to solve it's very hard to understand what you mean here.

Comment: @JonW updated with an help of example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use top hearts on the backgroung as a click areas. To indicate system's state you could use a little sparkle. Take a look at the picture. 
[image]

Comment: Won't the hand movements be noticeable ? Nice logic though

Comment: @joeyrohan 1) hot areas could be close to input field, so some taps could imitate unresponsiveness of the control of missing it; 2) let him tap anytime (before & after entering the name), just before proceeding.